# Plant has yellow things on it

Tags: identification, diagnosis, mushrooms

[image]
What are these things on my plant?? It started as small yellow dust then it grew to these weird fungi looking things on my plants. Is it time to throw it out?

Comment: What plant is it? I can't tell because its not in good condition, and how long have you had it? How long has it been in that pot, and does the pot have drainage holes? What soil did you  use in the pot?The yellow is either slime mould or fungal growth,  that won't be causing the plant problems, but may well indicate poor care/environmental conditions...

Comment: It is a lemon plant

Answer (score 2):

These are mushrooms, [Leucocoprinus birnbaumii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leucocoprinus_birnbaumii), aka Lepiota lutea living on the peat/organic matter.  This is a large percentage of soil less mixes and when it's wet it becomes an ideal home.
If you let them grow they will look like this
[image]
To deal with:

- change your water regime to water until the soil runs out the bottom and let the top inch of soil dry out
- remove them from the top of the soil and dispose
- stir up the top inch of the soil with a stick or similar tool to dry out the top of the soil

This stuff will not harm your plant but I do recommend not breathing in when you remove them or stir up the soil as dust and spores can be irritating to some

Comment: it's a type of slime mold